# произведение диагональных элементов массива и количество отрицательных элементов

Tags: c#, .net

Ранее был создан 2-мерный массив.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication11
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Insert N");
            int N = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Insert K");
            int K = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 1; j <= K; j++)
                {
                    if (i == j)
                    {
                        double[] z = { i * Math.Cos(K * K + 1) - Math.Abs(Math.Sin(2 * K) - 5.76) * i };
                        foreach (double a in z)
                        {

                            Console.WriteLine(a);
                            Console.ReadKey();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Найти произведение диагональных элементов массива и количество отрицательных элементов.

Answer (score 0):

Kоличество отрицательных элементов:

```
N * K
```

Произведение диагональных элементов:

```
Math.Min(N, K)! * (Math.Cos(K * K + 1) - Math.Abs(Math.Sin(2 * K) - 5.76))
```